# Django allauth google OAuth redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using Google OAuth for my Django App (via allauth package)

I have followed all standard configuration steps. In Google Developer console here's what i have:

**Authorized JavaScript origins**

```
https://example.com
```

**Authorized redirect URIs**

```
https://example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/ - login fails
http://example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/ - login succeeds
```

What i observe that if i have a **https** redirect URL in Authorized redirect URIs, it does not allow login and it fails with **redirect_uri_mismatch** Error. If i have a **http** redirect URL then the login succeeds.

What do i need to do to have a https enabled redirect URL ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adding the following in production settings.py fixed the problem for me:

ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL='https'

Comment: Thank you. Somehow the same code works for my localhost but fail in production and this was the fix that got me out of it

Comment: Gave you a bounty to get you over 1k points. My way of saying thanks. Forgot to add that my social provider was GitHub so your QnA was the same issue with the same fix for me

Comment: Where did you find this setting?

Comment: This is very useful and very hidden. Where did you find it? Google OAuth wouldnt work without this.

Answer (score 1):

****This worked for me** :

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com
2. Add without port http://127.0.0.1/accounts/google/login/callback/
3. Also Add http://localhost/accounts/google/login/callback/
4. *see the image in the link for detail*

[image]

Comment: Please also check your, URLS in urls.py

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in the following:

1. My website switched the access to HTTPS-only connections, while in Google API dashboard was `http://profile.example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/`.
2. So, I changed:
   from `http` -> `https` and it begins to work fine.
   [image]