# Django-allauth URL Returns callback error for github despite correct url

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am trying to implement all-auth using Github in my django project. I have set the callback url as per  [this](https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/) tutorial. So far, even if the login page for github shows up, it doesn't call back properly and I get this error in the url

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/github/login/callback/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=exDbVJKNYzUI

[This](https://github.com/cmkishores/real_estate_website) is the github repo of the project.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/github/login/callback/ 
is my authorization callback url set as per the tutorial.

Any insight to why the callback url is not working is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you defined authorization callback in the GitHub UI with https protocol than this setting solves the issue:
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL='https'

This is coming from the answer found here: [Django allauth google OAuth redirect_uri_mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784981/django-allauth-google-oauth-redirect-uri-mismatch-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for an answer to this,

if you configure the callback url to be from `127.0.0.1,` make sure you're requesting the callback from the same url. Although `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` both point to the same, it is different urls. So you will get url mismatch error.